# Cut a picture with the grip of another image

Tags: python, qgis-modeler, qgis-2.14

I have two raster images.
Let "A" and "B" my images
with "A" larger than "B"
I would like to cut A for it to have the same grip as B with the python script for use in the automation of a processing chain.
I use the SCRIPT QGIS 2.14 editor. and the modeler QGIS 2.14
I am available to answer all your questions so that you understand better if this is not yet the case.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with GDAL processing algorithm, and extent of the smaller image. First get the extent of the "B" image and save it as a string "xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax". Than use this tool:

```
import processing
processing.runalg('gdalogr:cliprasterbyextent', input, no_data, projwin, extra, output)
```

Here is a documentation: https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_extraction.html

You can also do this with console, without python: http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/~smudd/TopoTutorials/html/tutorial_raster_conversion.html#clipping-rasters-using-gdal